# Elementtree XML parsing stops at bracket

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am looking for a way to parse these translations out of the provided xml. Note that it could be a case that there are more than 2 terms provided as synonyms.

```
<root>
<languageGrp>
    <language type="Deutsch" lang="DE"/>
        <termGrp>
            <term>Apfel</term>
        </termGrp>
        <termGrp>
            <term>Braeburn</term>
        </termGrp>
</languageGrp>
<languageGrp>
    <language type="English" lang="EN"/>
        <termGrp>
            <term>Apple <xref Tlink="Deutsch:Apfelbaum">Tree</xref></term>
        </termGrp>
</languageGrp>
</root>
```

My current Code looks like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
liste = []
zsmliste = []
sprachliste= []


for element in root.iter():
    if element.get("type")== "Deutsch" or element.get("type")== "English":
        sprache= element.get("type")
        sprachliste.append(element.get("type"))
        liste = []
        besch = []
        zsmliste.append(liste)
    for term in element.findall("term"):
        liste.append(term.text)

dic = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(sprachliste, zsmliste)))
```

The problem is that elementtree stops parsing as soon as it hits the html xref, and therefore forgets about the Tree resulting in an insufficient output.

I thought about removing the xref with a regex beforehand, but everyone shouted at me, since its an xml. Any ideas how to solve this issue using elementtree?

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

all I had to do was use

```
"".join(term.itertext())
```

in the for loop, so that it looks like this:

```
for term in element.findall("term"):
    liste.append("".join(term.itertext()))
```

Sorry to bother you all.